# Adding columns while inserting a row in another table

Tags: mysql

### my tables are

table1 is

```
         class_name    subject_Name

              I class         telugu
              I class          hindi
              II class         telugu
              II class          hindi
```

table2 is

```
         exam_name    telugu   hindi

            unit 1      25      35
            unit 2      30      35
```

---

Now i insert a row in table1 with subject maths.That subject has added to the table2 as column and also check whether the subject(maths) is present in table2.

**my required output is**

---

table1 is

```
         class_name    subject_Name

              I class         telugu
              I class          hindi
              II class         telugu
              II class          hindi
              II class         maths
              III class          hindi
              III class         telugu
              III class          maths
```

table2 is

```
         exam_name    telugu   hindi  maths

            unit 1      25      35     35
            unit 2      30      35      25
```

---

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 2):

I would restructure table 2 to normalize it, using these columns:

exam_name,
subject, score

using the primary key exam_name, subject

You would then be able to query it to get all scores for the different subjects.

Table:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM t2;
+-----------+---------+-------+
| exam_name | subject | score |
+-----------+---------+-------+
| unit1     | hindi   |    25 |
| unit1     | telugu  |    45 |
| unit2     | math    |    15 |
| unit2     | telugu  |    25 |
+-----------+---------+-------+
```

You can now query:
First you need to find out all your subjects:

```
SELECT DISTINCT subject from t2;
```

Now you can use the subjects to create a pivot table:

```
SELECT exam_name, details.hindi, details.telugu, details.math 
FROM (
   SELECT exam_name, 
          SUM(if(subject='hindi',score,0)) AS hindi, 
          SUM(if(subject='telugu', score, 0)) AS telugu, 
          SUM(if(subject='math', score, 0)) AS math 
   FROM t2 GROUP BY exam_name

) AS details ;

+-----------+-------+--------+------+
| exam_name | hindi | telugu | math |
+-----------+-------+--------+------+
| unit1     |    25 |     45 |    0 |
| unit2     |     0 |     25 |   15 |
+-----------+-------+--------+------+
```

Look up pivot table for more detailed information. This solution assumes that there is only one entry for each exam_name/subject combination in the table.

You might be able to combined the two steps in one complex query. Depending on whether you call this from a script, that might or might not be preferable.